# Is there a way of updating a field on a table and affecting another field on another table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables in my database. So what i typically do is insert into tableOne (id, names) values (valueOneInt, valueOneVarChar) but i also want valueOneVarChar to be inserted into another table. Typically I do this separately, is there a shortcut for it?

Comment: This is often a bad idea, because you have the data in two places.  There are good reasons for doing what you want, but they are less common than you might think.  The answer to your question, though, is a trigger.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with a trigger. E.g.:

```
delimiter //

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER table_one_insert_tr
BEFORE INSERT ON table_one
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO table_two (varchar_col)
    VALUES (NEW.table_one_varchar);
END;

delimiter ;
```

Comment: @GordonLinoff agreed. I gave the concrete example of a `before insert` trigger's syntax, so that's what I wrote. After re-reading, I get why this statement might be a tad misleading.